# How to get a list off all server sessions in laravel?

Tags: php, session, frameworks, laravel

I'm using Laravel 3.
I want to know how many users are online , so i thought i might count all server sessions.
dose any one know how i could do this?
Note : I'm using `'driver' => 'file',`  in the session configuration.

Comment: Independent to Laravel, these sort of feature are normally easier to implement storing sessions into the database. You need to find a point where you can obtain the list of active sessions. That can be done by listing files in a directory ore querying a database table.

Comment: Ok! i'm using files for storing sessions, where can i find the files?

Comment: Please consult the technical documentation of the framework you're using to learn more about where those files are stored (this might be different to where PHP does it. If not the PHP manual has the location: http://www.php.net/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)

Comment: ghizzzzz! I would not ask if i could find it in the framework document !!!

Comment: Yet the database is a good idea, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Then most likely the framework uses the standard PHP session save-path. Also please consider the source-code of the software itself part of the documentation. It's written in there ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure sessions class to use a database to store session data, then you can query the sessions table to perform your queries, this is a feature in Laravel itself.

The exact method of configuring sessions will vary by the type of DB you are using, here's a guide to setting up sessions using databases: http://laravel.com/docs/session/config#database

Comment: Great, I almost found it my self. but you could have the green mark ;)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
Session::instance()->session['data'];
```

Comment: @WallacedeSouza 's comment should be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @Garre well this gives me only the current user, not all of the sessions..